# How do i deposit funds in my paypal acount from my web application in .net

Tags: asp.net, paypal-sandbox

I want to deposit money to my paypal account through web application in .net

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside and create your own button for your website. It will give you html code to place it in your website

Comment: Its a payable. i want it free

Comment: What do you mean by it's a payable? When you click on "create your button now" you go through the steps to customized your button